# How to make a connection between a keyboard's toolbar and view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table with labels that I want to go to the next and previous one after pushing the buttons, but the problem is that the toolbar exists in a UITextField extension.

I'm using selector to call the view controller's actions to reference the text fields in it, but I'm getting a "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.

Here is the 2 lines of code in the UITextField extension that adds the next and previous buttons.

```
let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: “Next”, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.nextButtonTapped(_:)))

let previousButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: “Prev”, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.previousButtonTapped(_:)))
```

Here are the functions in the HomeViewController that I want to be activated:

```
func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   //
}

func previousButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //
}
```

I understand that I might be getting the error because there is no actual connection between the current view controller and the toolbar but I'm not sure how to make a connection between them.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm referring to.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hello, I have implemented this but its not a "fancy" solution.. also iis on obj-c .. let me know if you want me to post it here

Comment: I can read objective-C, can I see it?

Comment: Take a view with subviews done, next and previous button and add the view as keyboard accessory view. Then implement the logic in button action method.

Comment: Im assuming you are implementing your toolbar as a accessory view

Comment: I am but it's added in the UITextField extension. So there is no connection with that code with the view controller.

Comment: you can add the button methods on your extension.. should work the same way

Comment: if you wan more help.. as this can be difficult on the comment section.. feel free to pm me.. fb.com/mrpatrnogic

Answer (score 1):

1- Subclass UITextfield and set it as the class for your textfields

```
class CustomTextField : UITextField
```

2- Create a protocol with a method "textField:moveToTextFieldWithTag:"

```
@protocol CustomTextFieldDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) textField:(CustomTextField*)textField moveToTextFieldWithTag:(int)tag;
@end
```

3- set the viewcontroller as the textfields delegate.

```
cell.textField.delegate = viewController;
```

4- set the indexpath.row + 1 as the textfields tag and the tableviewcells + 1 tag.

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row + 1;
cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row + 1;
```

5- create the toolbar buttons

```
UIBarButtonItem *prevButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"prev" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(prevAction)];

UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(nextAction)];
```

6- implement toolbar button methods on textfield subclass.

```
- (void)nextAction {
    int newTag = self.tag + 1;
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textField:moveToTextFieldWithTag:)]) {
        [((id<CustomTextFieldDelegate>)self.delegate) textField:self moveToTextFieldWithTag:newTag];
    } else {
        [self endEditing:YES];
    }
}
```

7- Implement protocol on viewController

```
//.h
@interface Controller : ParentClass <CustomTextFieldDelegate>
//.m
-(void)textField:(CustomTextField *)textField moveToTextFieldWithTag:(int)tag {
    UITableViewCell* celda = [self.tableView viewWithTag:tag];
    UIResponder *nextResponder = [celda.contentView viewWithTag:tag];
    if(nextResponder) {
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

> EDIT: This is how I add the buttons to the toolbar

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 44)];
NSArray *toolbarButtons = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:prevButton,nextButton, nil];
[toolBar setItems:toolbarButtons];
self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

Comment: sorry if it has syntax errors.. i had to write this here as i dont have XCode right now :(

Comment: How did you add the next and previous buttons to the toolbar? Are the buttons declared in the UITextfield subclass? Are the actions there too?

Comment: I have edited the answer so you can see how I add the buttons and the toolbar. Yes I created a method (addToolBar)  and the actions are there too, that was because that was more confortable to implement in my app.